# Sharepoint 2013 - create a search box in home page which searches from one list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, integrate-remedy-sp2013

I am relatively newbie here. I am trying to create a search box on the home page which results in a list of Terms and its Definitions on the same page. I have created a small layout to display this information. 
Can you advise best approach? 
- I have tried Search Box and Search Results which is not really working
- I am just about to try HTML form page with filter and list but doesn't sound like the best option. 
Regards.. Ben

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the query of the search results webpart (Webpart properties > Change Query)? I don't know why the combination of search box and results didn't work but with the search results webpart you have the option to change how search is performed by including default property filters. Have a look at the available filters. There is also one called ListUrl which should help you. Have a look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549987.aspx

Comment: Thanks YogaPanda and Suleyman. The issue with that probably was the Result Type template. Thats just my best guess. When I choose Search Result to point to a specific list, the result is it only shows the link to the list when I search for something. It doesn't go at List Item level and filter. Also, the search result is like a para which I preferred to either show a specific column of the list or the whole list for the keyword entered. Hope it makes sense what I explained

Answer (score 1):

What you will need is a Search Box web part and Search Result web part.
Drop two of those to your page, configure the Search Box web parts to only look at the specific list(Query: ListId:%7Dxxxx) and pointed the Search Result web part to Search Box. 
Since you mentioned homepage, be ware of the M$ bug that if you have two search box than the second one won't work. It's still a bug need to be fixed.

Comment: Hi YogaPanda, what you said about the Bug sounds right because the Search Result points to the Search Box on the page and if there is more then there is no way of pointing to "named" Search Box. Also, Search Box sounded like it is meant to be at a site level and not list level. Although there is an option to choose specific list in Change Query but looks like its for more than 1 list.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the SharePoint search query tool on CodePlex: https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/
Also check this MSDN article on the matter: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nadeemis/2012/11/09/sharepoint-2013-search-query-tool-released-on-codeplex/

hope it will be helpful ...

Answer (score 0):

If you can code, you could create a custom web part using .NET managed code or use JSOM in OOB content editor web part to search and query the keywords from your particular list using CAML.

Have a look at below article for more information and retrieving items using CAML.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

Else, for an OOB approach, have a look at OOB content query web part (CQWP) if you know your search terms (in advance) you can filter and render the results from a particular list/lib in a site or its sub sites.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thanks for the response. Like you said it cannot be dynamic, so I might not be able to use it. I am giving it a try. There is a lot of info on it, so should be able to test it out.